# Get absolute (base) url in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, haml

Right now, I do a

```
get '/' do
  set :base_url, "#{request.env['rack.url_scheme']}://#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}"
  # ...
  haml :index
end
```

to be able to use options.base_url in the HAML index.haml. 
But I am sure there is a far better, DRY, way of doing this. Yet I cannot see, nor find it. (I am new to Sinatra :))

Somehow, outside of *get*, I don't have request.env available, or so it seems. So putting it in an include did not work.

How do you get your base url?

Comment: How is `options.base_url` not DRY?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A couple things.

1. `set` is a class level method, which means you are modifying the whole app's state with each request
2. The above is a problem because potentially, the base url could be different on different requests eg `http://foo.com` and `https://foo.com` or if you have multiple domains pointed at the same app server using DNS

A better tactic might be to define a helper

```
helpers do
  def base_url
    @base_url ||= "#{request.env['rack.url_scheme']}://#{request.env['HTTP_HOST']}"
  end
end
```

If you need the base url outside of responding to queries(not in a get/post/put/delete block or a view), it would be better to set it manually somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I read about helpers, but did not get far enough to dive into that deeply. Thanks. It seems that the answer was there :)

Comment: `@base_url ||= "#{request.scheme}://#{request.host}"`

Comment: Might need to add `#{request.port}` if you are not running your httpd on the standard ports (like 443 for https)

Answer (score 40):

You can get it using `request.base_url` too =D (take a look at [rack/request.rb](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb))

Comment: This looks like the best way, since source code as basically does what the other answer suggests doing manually and IMPORTANTLY includes the port optionally if it's non-default