# How to refer to root path in Sinatra views

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is there a way to refer to the root URL of my Sinatra app? Say in one of the views I'd like to do the following:

```
<a href="<%= ROOT_PATH/cats %>">Show all cats</a>
```

Does Sinatra provide a magic helper for `ROOT_PATH` or it's equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also the [`uri` helper](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sinatra/Sinatra/Helpers#uri-instance_method)

```
#uri(addr = nil, absolute = true, add_script_name = true) ⇒ Object
```

> Also known as: `url`, `to`
>
> Generates the absolute URI for a given path in the app. Takes Rack
>   routers and reverse proxies into account.

For your example:

```
<a href="<%= uri('/cats') %>">Show all cats</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be accessible through `request.base_url`

Which is implemented by [rack](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb) using:

```
def base_url
  url = "#{scheme}://#{host}"
  url << ":#{port}" if port != DEFAULT_PORTS[scheme]
  url
end
```

[Get absolute (base) url in sinatra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950234/get-absolute-base-url-in-sinatra)

Comment: Thanks! And that's available in the view as `<%= request.base_url %>`.